# How to create a MVVM for a user control without exposing all the internals to the consumer?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, user-controls

I'm designing some complex UserControls using MVVM. The datacontext of the UserControls handles all the logic and provides the results of the UserControl interaction to the control's consumer.

The problem I'm facing is that looks like internal does not work for bindings and if I try to bind to a source property that is not public binding does not work. If I have to open (amek public) all the source properties of my VM top be able to bind them then I'm opening the internals of the UserControl and the consumer:

1. Is confused about what properties use.
2. Can break things using properties not intended for external usage.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Well, looking at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643.aspx) looks like sources have to be always public, right. But then I still face the problem of making internals public. Any solution to this?

***Example:***

You create a generic UserControl. The control should be a blackbox that takes a query supplied by the enduser, shows (somehow) to him the rows returned by the query and lets the UserControl consumer take the selected value. The control is implemented with a Combobox  that shows the rows.

The UserControl is inside UserControl.xaml and there is a UserControlVM.cs file with the ViewModel of the UserControl.

The ViewModel contains the query to be executed, the list of items returned by the query and the selected item. The list of items and the selected item are public to be able to be binded to the UserControl.

The consumer uses one instance of the UserControl inside its window and one instance of the UserControlVM inside its window viewmodel. The problem I face is the enduser having access to the list of items returned by the query when he only should have access to the selected item.

Answer (score 0):

All property targets for the `Binding` class need to be public

Here is a possible alternative solution:

Your `DataContext` (if it's a `ViewModel`), is likely to Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.
If so, then when you set the `DataContext` (`ViewModel`) on the `UserControl`, just subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event handler, then write logic in your code-behind to manipulate your control depending on the changed data.

Comment: But then you're moving the logic to the UI and MVVM loses one of its benefits :S

Answer (score 0):

Data that is an implementation detail to your class should not be public, but in my opinion, you should not even want to bind to this type of data anyway.  The data that is bound to the view should be public properties and commands of your view-model.  Keep in mind that the view-model defines **what** your UI is.

The public properties that the user interface does not allow to change should only implement getters, not setters.  The public properties that can only be changed under certain conditions should enforce those conditions in the setters.  The view-model should provide and house all of the UI logic (properties and commands).

You should also wrap your view-model in unit tests that tests all of that.

Update based on comment feedback:

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
     private bool _showSomething;
     public bool ShowSomething
     {
         get { return _showSomething; }
         set
         {
             _showSomething = value;
             RaisePropertyChanged("ShowSomething");
             RaisePropertyChanged("TheThing");
         }
     }

     public Something TheThing
     { 
         get
         {
             if(_showSomething) { return _theThing; }
             return _theOtherThing;
         }
     }

     private Something _theThing;
     private Something _theOtherThing;

}
```

Edit*: The following may be closer to what is desired based on comments.

```
public interface IQueryControl
{
    string Query { get; set; } //view passes query in
    ReadOnlyCollection<string> QueryResultDescriptions { get; } //bind to combo items
    string SelectedQueryDescription { get; set; } //bind to combo selection
    object SelectedItem { get; } //resulting object
}

public class UserControlVM : ViewModelBase, IQueryControl
{
    private string _query;
    private ObservableCollection<object> _queryResults;
    private ReadOnlyCollection<string> _externalResults;
    private object _selectedResult;

    public string Query 
    { 
        get { return _query; } 
        set 
        {
            _query = value; 
            RaisePropertyChanged("Query");
            UpdateQueryResults(); 
        }
    }

    private void UpdateQueryResults()
    {
        //Do query which allocates / updates _queryResults;
        _externalResults = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>((from entry in _queryResults select entry.ToString()).ToList<string>());
        RaisePropertyChanged("QueryResultDescriptions");
    }

    public ReadOnlyCollection<string> QueryResultDescriptions
    {
        get { return _externalResults; }
    }

    public string SelectedQueryDescription
    {
        get { return _selectedResult.ToString(); }
        set
        {
            SelectResult(value);
        }
    }

    private void SelectResult(string value)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> lookup = _queryResults.ToDictionary<object, string>((result) => { return result.ToString(); });
        if (lookup.ContainsKey(value))
        {
            _selectedResult = lookup[value];
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedQueryDescription");
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
        }
        else
        {
            //throw something
        }
    }

    public object SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedResult; }
    }

}
```

Comment: I have an UserControl that allows to select one thing base on other things. I would like to give to the consumer of the UserControl only the selected thing (as he shouldn't care about the other things). The control has lists of data read from Db and other things that perfectly fits with the MVVM paradigm. That's why I thing that  "The data that is bound to the view should be public" is wrong. In a perfect world bindings should work with "Internal" modifier as it is what the data really is, it's internal to the UserControl, but I ned to Bind it.

Comment: You can do that just fine.  You store the master list of things in an internal, expose a public property that provides the thing they need to see, when the related properties are changed, update the public "thing" and raise a property notification change of the public thing.  I'll update the answer with detail.

Comment: Nice example, consider changing the public bool ShowSomething to public ObservableCollection<Things> {get; private set;}. I bind this property to a ComboBox and I update TheThing with the selected item. You need to make public the ObservableCollection property when this data is not required by the enduser (it's only something required by the UserControl)

Comment: It may be best if you update the original post with code details on what you are doing.  It sounds like maybe you have a view-model that is not in a 1-1 relationship with a view (the user control being one view, with a possible second view that maybe consumes the user control).  It doesn't need to be your production code, but should be representative of your production code.

Comment: I've added a conceptual example that maybe it's better than code to present the issue. Tell me if you still prefer some code after reading the edit. Thanks for helping.

Comment: I expanded on the code I posted, hopefully this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Your implementation is exactly what I'm doing. The problem here is that the UserControl consumer only needs/wants to have the SelectedItem. He does not care about QueryResultDescriptions (and he shouldn't have access to it as it could add items to the collection by mistake introducing errors). With your (and mine) implementation the internals binded are public.

Comment: You can't give the data and not give the data unless you add a layer.  You have to give that data to the control.  You can probably fix the problem of consumers seeing it as a public method by adding a layer, but at the end of the day I think you will still have to expose this data in a nested layer.  You can't give it to them and not give it to them.  One way I might still be able to help is if you posted a test case you expected to pass.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I've found (but I advance you that does not work if your ViewModel needs constructor parameters).

1. Make the ViewModel internal while maintaining the binding properties public.
2. Create a class "UserControlData" that contains the data the usercontrol will offer to the end user
3. Offer an instance of that class thru an UserControl dependence property.
4. The usercontrol consumer will have to bind the UserControlData instance in its viewmodel to get the usercontrol results.